# How to create custom ionic/Cordova plugin for getting openUDID in iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, udid

We were creating a ionic app to fetch the UDID for ios device, since UDID is restricted by Apple I am trying to integrate the openUDID available in https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID. 
Need to create a plugin so that we can access the native files which generate the openUDID. 
Help me out creating the custom plugin, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this plugin:

https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID

It's available also for iOS platform:

Source code: https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID/tree/master/src/ios